# How to script changing the node name of a client in chef from the client without knife

Tags: chef-infra, knife, cloud-init

I have a "golden image" AMI and I want to put it in an autoscaling group that will take the image, rename it, and execute the run-llst. I just spent most of the day with cloud-config's chef feature, and it's not working because there are too many inconsistencies between the original chef environment and whatever cloud-config is using. It's also going to be less reliable and slow in the long-run because will have to chef from scratch every time. I want to take an instance that's had chef run on it and start from there. Looking around all I see are ways to do this manually and using knife. Is there a way to rewrite a few files and register the image with the chef server that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [example I showed you last time](https://github.com/coderanger/brix/tree/master/packer). Thats exactly what it is for. The AMI has Chef pre-installed and has the validation certificate. At boot time, cloud-init runs the script I showed you which generates the client config and initial run list, and then registers with the chef server.

Comment: For what I need to do, it turns out that all that's necessary is to remove the client.pem and rename the node. Since the node was previouslt converged under a different name, all the rest can stay the same. Thanks for helping me through it.

Comment: To be clear, the following works for me: rm -f /etc/client.pem && echo "server-app-$(date %+s)" >> /etc/chef/client.rb

Comment: Why is there a client.pem in the AMI at all? I wouldn't use chef-client to build an AMI (thats what solo is for) but if you must you should be removing that during the AMI build process.

Comment: @numb3rs1x I do agree with coderanger on last comment, I'm on a lightly different path for the infrastructure but I also keep the original VM booting periodically to keep it up to date). I've choose a quick and dirty path with a script which: 1) boot the VM, 2) copy client.pem from /root to /etc/chef 3) run chef-client 4) remove /etc/chef/client.pem and 5) shutdown the VM. I've no node_name in the client_rb as the provisioning takes care of changing the hostname (vagrant with vshpere plugin for my case).

Comment: @coderanger yeah, I suppose it makes more sense to remove the client.pem before creating the AMI. I was not accounting for that step in that part of the process.